# Totalcross: Geração de QR Code

Tags: qrcode, totalcross

Por gentileza, é possível gerar QR Code através de código TotalCross?
Em caso positivo, como devo implementar? Qual classe/interface devo usar?
Em caso negativo, alguma previsão de disponilizarem essa funcionalidade?

Comment: Atualmente, não gera QR Code. Tem algumas alternativas para isso; pôde-se consumir um webservice que retorne o QR Code. Outra alternativa seria criar o bitmap através da especificação do QR Code e por em um objeto tipo `Image`

Comment: Obrigado, Jefferson!

Vou avaliar qual delas é a mais interessante para a nossa solução!

Comment: A propósito, qual o tamanho mais adequado para uma tela de smartphone? O que quero dizer é que esse QR Code pode ser lido por um outro dispositivo. O objeto tipo Image do TotalCross permite que essa imagem QR Code seja realmente identificada e reconhecida por um aplicativo que leia QR Codes?

Grato mais uma vez!

Comment: o tamanho mais adequado para ser lido em outro dispositivo? Bem, isso vai depender da qualidade do aparelho leitor. A construção do QR Code vai lhe fornecer espaços de dimensão arbitrária (quantizada) que precisam ser brancos ou pretos, então você pode fazer o upscale de modo algorítmico. Sobre fazer o upscale usando diretamente o `Image.setScale`, vou ver aqui como é feito o _stretching_ da imagem

Comment: Pelo que vi, `Image.getScaledInstance` não faz interpolação de pixels, então creio que é plausível usá-la para fazer upscale de imagens mantendo as bordas nítidas. `Image.getSmoothedScale` vai fazer uma interpolação para dar uma aparência mais suave, então ela não deve ser usada jamais para qr Code, seja upscale ou downscale